# How to deal with assets in mx datagrid header renderer

Tags: apache-flex

I have an application which uses an mx datagrid with custom item renderers. In every refresh, the datagrid is reconstructed. I found the application has memory leaks, after profiling, I found that the reason is binding with assets

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: I've solved a lot of memory issues for clients by re-writing itemRenderers to not use Binding.  But, since you have shared no code it's tough to direct you.  "In every refresh, the DataGrid is reconstructued."  What refresh?  You mean reloading the app?  Or replacing the dataProvider?  Or something different?

Comment: The data is retrieved from the database, and if there is any changes, there will be refreshment of the datagrid. I'm doing a test to make the datagrid refresh every time even when data does not change to correct the problem in the case when data might change frequently.

Comment: Actually, in Flex you should prefer reusing instances instead of creating new instances. Also, are you using an inline renderer or are you using a dedicated component defined in its own .as file? Inline renderers may cause leaks when bindings are applied.

Comment: @FlorianSalihovic I tried reusing the header renderers, but I still had the memory leak, and the custom column header renderer is an mxml file, it is a canvas having many components, the problem is that when i remove all the components and keep only the combobox, there is a memory leak

Comment: Any chance to see some code? Perhaps on a github repo?

Comment: @FlorianSalihovic The code for the column header renderer which prevents it to be garbage collected is very simple `<mx:Canvas><mx:ComboBox/></mx:Canvas>. When I profile this codem the memory keeps increasing because header renderer is not garbage collected, but when I use other components, there will be no problem, for example, dropdownlist

Answer (score -2):

DropdownList is a spark component, whereas what you are trying to get rid of is an MX combobox.
Remember, not so easy to maintain an application that has multiple event dependencies...
Some times we ask the question, why do we really create new header renders and replace the old one? May be trying to reuse those header renderers (after updating the data provider of a combobox, or updating the sorting image) will solve the problem, since we have the same instances of headerrenderers on our Flex datagrid.

Comment: As I said in my question, I've tried with both mx and spark combobox